# (Buildroot raspberry pi 3) Kernel panic not syncing : attempted to kill init

Tags: embedded-linux, init, busybox, buildroot

it's been nearly a week having this issue:
I used buildroot-2017.02 to build firstly the toolchain for raspberry pi 3, then I cross-compiled the kernel using this toolchain. Then I flash the output image "sdcard.img" to the SD.

When I turn on the raspberry I have this kernel panic :

Kernel Panic error

[image]

I searched a lot about this issue and tried some fixes but it doesn't seem to be working.

PS: I'm new to this, don't have much experience in building kernels.

**Edit :**

When I plug the keyboard to see the errors it freezes :

Kernel Panic \w keyboard

[image]

Comment: The screenshot unfortunately doesn't show the actual error - it's a bit higher up. However, it looks like init doesn't want to start. The most likely cause for this is that it is linked to the wrong libc, i.e. it can't find the libc it was linked against in the root filesystem. This is a typical symptom of changing the toolchain without doing 'make clean' in Buildroot.

Comment: I think I already did it, should I build the toolchain and kernel at the same time again? (I used glibc with gcc 5.x and kernel 4.9).

Comment: The kernel (probably) has nothing to do with it - if you get that far, the kernel is OK. It is init itself, i.e. the rootfs, which is wrong. Just to be sure, however, can you try to capture the error output itself - including the lines just before the beginning of the first stack trace? You might still have a working keyboard, in which case "shift-PgUp" should still work. Also, the trace you posted mentions kernel 4.4.43, not 4.9...

Comment: When I use the keyboard the pi freezes I can't do anything

Comment: Could you use a serial port so you can get the output before the stack trace?

Comment: I never did it, I'll search and try it

Comment: You only mention building the toolchain and kernel, and absolutely nothing about a root filesystem (other than an output image). The crux of your question revolves around a proper rootfs. That's the rationale for using Buildroot. You can use crosstool-NG to build a toolchain. You can build the Linux kernel straight from the source. You don't need Buildroot to do either of those tasks. Bottom line: what, if anything, did you do to configure for the rootfs?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, I used the default configs for the section "Filesystem Images" it output a rootfs.ext4 file and of course the "sdimage.img" that I need to flash.

For the serial port I used the FTDI serial to usb and command "screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200" it didn't work it shows "Screen terminating" or something like that.

Comment: The salient configuration information that you need to provide is not the type(s) of filesystem image (the rootfs image is obviously readable since the kernel was able to mount it and is actually accessing it), but rather ***what are the contents of that rootfs***?  What did you do for the `System configuration --> Init system` and the `Target packages` for the rootfs, especially `Busybox` and its configuration? Did you ever perform a `make raspberrypi3_defconfig`, IOW how did you establish those *"default configs"* that you refer to?

Comment: I basically didn't touch 'System configuration' and 'Target Package' I ran the make raspberrypi3_defconfig and just changed the root password that's it, and it's using the Busybox init system

Comment: Regarding "screen": it means /dev/ttyUSB0 does not exist, or is not writable by you.Is the FTDI cable plugged in correctly? Is it really /dev/ttyUSB0 and not something lese? Are you in the correct group (dialout on Debian/Ubuntu)?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. There is no /dev/ttyUSB0 before I plug it, it appears only when I plug it.

Comment: I used a config from a blog, it is using 'systemV' as Init system, and it's working. There isn't much difference in the other settings. Is this an issue with busybox?